# Fancybox not working in Rails 3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, fancybox

I'm using `gem 'fancybox-rails'`

Here is what my html is like (I'm trying to display the hidden div with class `item_comments`):

```
<div class="details">
    <ul class="items">
        <li><a class="comments" href="#">show comments</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="item_comments">
        <ul>
            <% comments.each do |comment| %>
                <li><%= comment.comment %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my JS for this:

```
$(".comments").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.item_comments').fancybox();
        return false;
    });
```

**PS.** I've tried manually including fancy box js, css and images also -- still won't work :(

Comment: your anchor tag is not closed properly

Comment: Thanks I added that in (I just missed it here in the question -- the actual code has the ending tag). Still doesn't work. I think I'll give some other modal script a shot instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but you don't have a  tag in the "show comments" link. Because of that, your .parent() functions might not be working.

Comment: do you mean "don't have a **closing** tag"?